# Custom styling for tinyMCE nonEditable element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, tinymce

I'm using tinyMCE 4 in AngularJS ([angular-ui-tinymce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-tinymce)). I'm trying to use the [noneditable plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/noneditable/)  to get some variable that I have predefined to show up nicely. I have a plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/AImGWCDO6a1J6VC7kD73?p=preview

Now my settings for tinyMCE is as shown

```
vm.settings = {
  menubar: false,
  toolbar: 'firstButton | secondButton',

  plugins: 'noneditable',
  noneditable_regexp: [ 
    /<my-variable>(.*?)<\/my-variable>/g,
    /<other-variable>(.*?)<\/other-variable>/g
  ],
  extended_valid_elements :'my-variable,other-variable',
  custom_elements: '~my-variable,~other-variable',
  content_style: "my-variable: {background: yellow;} other-variable: {background: blue;}",

  setup: function(editor){
    editor.addButton('firstButton', {
      text: 'Insert first',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function () {
        editor.insertContent('<my-variable>MY-VARIABLE</my-variable>');
      }
    });
    editor.addButton('secondButton', {
      text: 'Insert second',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function () {
        editor.insertContent('<other-variable>OTHER-VARIABLE</other-variable>');
      }
    });
  }
```

};

And I just call these on my tinyMCE object with
`<div ui-tinymce="vm.settings" ng-model="vm.content"></div>`
So it's pretty standard.

My question is: How can I make `<my-variable>` and `<other-variable>` have different styles? When TinyMCE translates them they only seem to take on the class of 'mceNonEditable'. I would rather not have to add a class attribute to my custom tags as they are meant to be parsed in a later stage, and it's much easier if there are no attributes on them.

Comment: Your `content_style` is missing a `:` It should be `content_style: "my-variable: {background: yellow;} other-variable: {background: blue;}"`

Comment: @jasonscript Added. No change in behaviour though.